# how to install nanoid in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, es6-modules, nanoid

I tried importing nanoid into NestJS and got this error:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ....
> ...  Instead change the require of index.js in ... to a dynamic import()
> which is available in all CommonJS modules.

The import code was:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';   //wont import, gives error
import { User } from './data-objects/user.object';
```

I also tried variation of the import statement:

```
// I tried this alternative
import * as nanoid from 'nanoid';

// Also tried this
const nanoid = require ( 'nanoid' );
```

Nothing worked.

Why is this error happening and how am I supposed to install nanoid in NestJS ?

Answer (score 15):

I could not find a straight answer to my question with a simple search and only after some research on [nanoid github issue #365](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/issues/365) found the answer.

##### Some background on the issue

- On Jun 08 2022 nanoid Ver.4.0.0 was released with a breaking change.
- It has a new feature that where it now supports only ESM applications
- This makes it non-compatible to applications using CommonJS. [Link to the change log...](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/issues/365)
- The nanoid support team promised to continue supporting Ver.3.x.x as as needed until support for EMS in nodejs & nestjs comes along.

Until a day comes when NestJS supports ESM, you will have to stay with nanoid Version 3.x.x

##### How to fix

- First uninstall the nanoid version 4.x.x : `npm uninstall nanoid`
- Then install the ne version and any other future 3.x.x : `npm install nanoid@^3.0.0`

The source for my solution came from a comment in the github issue [@ayushsharma82](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/issues/365#issuecomment-1167075436).